# A mechanism to free multiple regions on the heap at once

Tags: c, free

Just to achieve clarity in my project, i want to avoid using `free(3)` in this manner:

```
free(ptr1);
free(ptr2);
.
.
.
free(ptrn);
```

So i had added a macro in this fashion

```
#define stop_point NULL
#define free_space(...){ \
void *ptrs[] = {__VA_ARGS__,stop_point};              \
for(int i=0;ptrs[i]!=stop_point;i++) free(ptrs[i]);}
```

And using it as following:

```
free_space(ptr1,ptr2,...ptrn);
```

I think this mechanism works but there is one problem, e.g. in the above line, if `ptr2` is NULL, then other pointers following `ptr2` (i.e. ptr3,ptr4...) will not get `free`.
What i need is a better `stop_point`. How can i achieve that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different sentinel. Change the macro to:

```
#define free_space(...) { \
    void *ptrs[] = { __VA_ARGS__, ptrs }; \
    for (int i = 0; ptrs[i] != ptrs; i++) free(ptrs[i]); }
```

or use the length of the array created from the list:

```
#define free_space(...) { \
    void *ptrs[] = { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof ptrs / sizeof *ptrs; i++) free(ptrs[i]); }
```

Comment: Alternatively: `i != sizeof(ptrs)/sizeof(*ptrs)`